# Put two icons inside of an input field with jsDelivr semantic-ui

Tags: html, formatting, icons, ejs, jsdelivr

I was trying to put another icon in an input tag that alredy has an icon, but when I put it, gets over the other icon like this
[image]
I just want to put the eye icon to the right side, i put the code to so if anyone finds an error.

```
<div class="field">
 <div class="ui left icon input">
   <i class="lock icon"></i>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
   <i class="eye icon"></i>
 </div>
 <div onclick="Change()" class="ui large fluid teal button" data-show>Show password</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So for now I will just replace the lock icon with the eye icon because I still not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

make it absolute as right:16px

Comment: It still don't works, but thanks in helping me. I think I will just replace the lock icon with the eye icon, but i will still wait for another answer.